# How to add animated splash screen in our application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to add animated splash screen in our application.

Comment: All are telling about how to make an animation using UIImageView, either they didn't read the question or they are quite intelligent :-)

Comment: Somebody plz answer the question cited above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use sequence of images, here is code:

```
for(NSInteger i=1;i<=totalImages;i++){
        NSString *strImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Activity_%d",i];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:strImage ofType:@"png"]];
        [imageArray addObject:image];
    }
    splashImageView.animationImages = imageArray;
    splashImageView.animationDuration = 0.8;
```

and just call startAnimation and endAnimation method of UIImageView.

Comment: where this code placed. is splashImageView UIImage view object if this is splash screen object, how to get it

Answer (score 3):

Its very simple...I had used it in to begin my app with splashView.Hope it vil help you....
In AppDelegate.m:

application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
UIImage* image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash.jpg"];
splashView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
[window addSubview:splashView];
[window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
[self performSelector:@selector(removeSplash) withObject:self afterDelay:2];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

To remove splashView:

```
-(void)removeSplash{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:window cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [splashView removeFromSuperview];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Old Answer:**

Well this is not possible yet. You can not make any Animation on **Splash Screen**. But you can make it via `UIViewController` class which will look like a **Splash Screen**. Remove the `default.png` image from your project by which user cant see the **Default Splash Screen**. Then in your first `ViewController` class you can make an animation using an `array of images` as was told above already. And in `viewDidLoad:` method make a `NSTimer` then hold the `View` according to you. After finish the time limit of `NSTimer` navigate your next `ViewController` view.

**Edit:**

I found an alternative solution to make it animated. We can show a **.gif** image in `webView` and it looks perfect!

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"animated" ofType: @"gif"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
[self.webView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[self.webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"image/gif" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

Make this view as a rootView of your app and after few delay navigate your next View.
Remember make its `userIntractionEnabled:` false i.e. user cant scroll it.

Full description see here [Animated Splash Screen in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745055/animated-splash-screen-in-iphone/12745659#12745659)

Answer (score 2):

I do this by creating an array of images because gif is not supported format

Just add image frames of your movieclip for eg: {Splashbackground1,Splashbackground2,Splashbackground3 are sequence of images}

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // create the view that will execute our animation for elephant
    CGRect splashscreenmovieclipframe = CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,480.0f, 320.0f); //set co-ordinate here i use full screen
    splashscreenmovieclip = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:splashscreenmovieclipframe];

    // load all the frames of our animation
    splashscreenmovieclip.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"Splashbackground.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"Splashbackground1.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"Splashbackground2.png"],
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"Splashbackground3.png"],
                                             nil];

    // all frames will execute in 1.75 seconds
    splashscreenmovieclip.animationDuration =7;
    // repeat the annimation forever
    splashscreenmovieclip.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    // start animating
    [splashscreenmovieclip startAnimating];
    // add the animation view to the main window
    [self.view addSubview:splashscreenmovieclip];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:7.0f target:self selector:@selector(Gotomainmenuview:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)Gotomainmenuview:(NSTimer *)theTimer 
{
    // write your code here for counter update 
    [splashscreenmovieclip removeFromSuperview];
    newclasstojump *mmvc=[[newclasstojump alloc]initWithNibName:@"newclasstojump" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:mmvc.view];
}
```